# Outlook VSTO - disable AppointmentItem window while loading data

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have a Outlook VSTO plugin developed for Outlook 2016. It loads a UserControl whenever a new meeting window is opened. The UserControl fetches some data at startup. I would like to disable the UI till this data load is complete. For example, users should not be allowed to enter anything in the "To"/"Subject" etc. Ideally, show a dialog showing "Loading data.." or something similar.

I am looking for something similar to what is mentioned here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2cbf9c7c-f562-4028-9673-d8e5cdf0dc77/splash-screen-for-vsto-application?forum=vsto

Thanks
Vik

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to set the [Control.Enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enabled?view=netcore-3.1) property which sets a value indicating whether the control can respond to user interaction. For example:

```
// Add a GroupBox to a form and set some of its common properties.
private void AddMyGroupBox()
{
   // Create a GroupBox and add a TextBox to it.
   GroupBox groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
   TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
   textBox1.Location = new Point(15, 15);
   groupBox1.Controls.Add(textBox1);

   // Set the Text and Dock properties of the GroupBox.
   groupBox1.Text = "MyGroupBox";
   groupBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

   // Disable the GroupBox (which disables all its child controls)
   groupBox1.Enabled = false;

   // Add the Groupbox to the form.
   this.Controls.Add(groupBox1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. But I am looking at disabling the outlook controls such as "To", "Subject", "Send" button etc and not the form with in my add-in.

Comment: You need to develop a form region to replace the default Outlook UI in inspector windows.

Comment: There is no trivial way to disable built-in controls.

Comment: Thanks. Will consider that.